# Annotatable Control Flow Graph with Boost?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost

I have a **control flow graph** representing a single procedure of my intermediate language code. Nodes and Edges are annotated via vertex/edge properties and contain instructions resp branch information.

Now I want to perform data flow analysis on this graph and feed that graph into each data flow analysis module. Each module should be able to **annotate the CFG** with its own data.
Problems I need to solve:

- I don't know upfront **how many annotations** are introduced by the data flow analysis modules (because I will implement additional analysis modules in the future)
- I don't know anything about the **type of annotation** introduced by a specific data flow analysis module
- Each data flow analysis module should exist **independently** from the other modules, i.e. module A shouldn't be concerned about the annotations introduced by module B

Do you see any chance to realize all of the above requirements?
Any comments or advises are highly appreciated

**Update:**
To be more specific, I basically want to **decouple** my annotations from the Graph type. When using the usual vertex/edge properties the Graph type itself is always "polluted" (and is therefore dependent on the vertex/edge property types) by the contained property types.

Comment: The original version of your question mentioned GraphProperty class that you have. Does that class already handle storing arbitrary set of annotation of different types? I need this to understand how much of detailed answer you need.

Comment: I removed my Graph convenience class from the post because i thought it would confuse people. I have this graph convenience class which stores a few properties which will never change. The annotations are meant to store information, that is unique to each dataflow module. That's why I want to decouple these informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the "Using Property Maps" chapter of the documentation of the boost graph library.  Especially the "Constructing an Exterior Property Map" section.  If that doesn't answer your question, could you clarify what is missing?

Comment: Do you by chance have an example on how to use exterior property maps together with a simple graph? The boost documentation on this seems to be pretty vague

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any standard way to associate unbounded set of properties to an adjacenty_list. Since I assume you care about performance, I'd suggest the following approach. First, instroduce 'tag' types for every property you want to use, much like BGL does. The properties need not be defined in the same place -- a module implementing specialized analysis can define a tag type in it's header or source file. For example:

```
struct execution_count { typedef int value_type; };
```

The `value_type` typedef should give the type of value the property has.

Then, create new graph type derived from adjacently_list, and add new method, `get_dynamic_property_map`. This method will return a property map for a specific
custom property. The class `dynamic_property_map` will be explained later. It
is assumed that your algorithm call this method on start, and this method need
not be very fast.

```
std::map<std::type_info, boost::any> dynamic_properties_;
template<class Property>
dynamic_property_map<typename Property::value_type>
get_dynamic_property_map()
{
    typedef typename Property::value_type V;
    if (!dynamic_properties_.count(typeid(Property))
        dynamic_properties_.insert(make_pair(typeid(Property),
            new dynamic_property_map<V>();
    boost::any a = dynamic_properties_[typeid(Property)];
    return *boost::any_cast<dynamic_property_map<V>*>(a);
}
```

The trick here is to use boost::any and type_info to store arbitrary set of property maps for a graph, without specifying the types in advance.

The `dynamic_property_map` class takes a vertex and returns the value, and in the simplest form can be:

```
template<class T>
class dynamic_property_map : public std::vector<T> {};
```

This assumes that (1) vertex_descriptor is integer and (2) you don't add new vertices after map is created. If you add new vertices, then you should override operator[] to check if the index is beyond the end. If so, resize the vector.

If `vertex_descriptor` is not integer, you need more coding. The `dynamic_property_map` should also has graph type as template parameter, and should also hold a reference to the graph. The `get_dynamic_property_map` will have to be adjusted. The `operator[]` will have to do this:

```
template<class V, class G>
V& dynamic_property_map<V, G>::operator[](
      typename graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor v)
{
    int index = get(vertex_index_t, g_ /* member referring to graph */, v);
    return std::vector<V>::operator[](index);
}
```

You probably need a way to store properties on edges too. Then, add another overload like above.

Unfortunately, BGL does not support 'autonumbering' of edges -- but you can derive from `adjacency_list` and override methods that add edges to fill in edge_index_t property.

Hope this helps.

Note 0. I did not even try to compile the above code. While I had a working solution once, it's now several computers behind.

Note 1. Map from type_info won't actually work, as type_info does not define operator<. You can key define such operator yourself, or put result of `type_info::name` into the map -- which is technically less reliable.

Note 2. Deriving from `std::vector` is used for exposition only. Decide yourself if that's a good idea for final solution.

Comment: All in all I like your solution, though I'm not sure how to deal with the problem described under Note 1 in your answer. Any more concrete iIdeas?

Comment: struct type_info_ptr_compare {
   bool operator()(const std::type_info* p1, 
                   const std::type_info* p2) 
   {
      return p1->before(*p2);
   }
};

std::map<type_info*, boost::any, type_info_ptr_compare>
     dynamic_properties_.

Note that the original recipe had a map from type_info. That was thinko - you need map from type_info*, since type_info is not copyable.